# Adding array to firebase array object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularfire

I have an array of objects that look like the following:

```
[  
   {  
      name:"dude",
      id:"333"
   },
   {  
      name:"Another dude",
      id:"777"
   },
   {  
      name:"Dude three",
      id:"123"
   }
]
```

Under certain circumstances, I'm trying to create a sub-array, history, for a specific student and then save it back to firebase.  The below javascript shows how I am doing this.

```
 var studentsRef = new Firebase("http://firebase.url");
 $scope.students = $firebaseArray(studentsRef); 
 var studentToLogin = $scope.students[0];
 if(!studentToLogin.history){
   studentToLogin.history = [];
 };                    
 studentToLogin.in = 1;
 studentToLogin.history.push({timeIn: new Date()});
 $scope.students.$save(studentToLogin);
 console.log(studentToLogin);
```

Doing this does make `studentToLogin.in = 1` push to firebase successfully (note that without using `$save` it does not save to firebase) but the array is ignored.  Logging this object to the console shows the array present.

What's the best way to do this? Or am I doing something wrong with this way?